# TextView and Checkbox inside LinearLayout, but Checkbox disappears

Tags: android, checkbox, android-linearlayout

I have TextView and CheckBox inside LinearLayout. Checkbox must appear to the right of the TextView. In the Eclipse View, Checkbox appear, but when i launch app in my device checkbox disappears.

This is Eclipse view (Checkbox is the star):

[image]

This is part of my xml file:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_relative_imagen_poli"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="100">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_imgfoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/pld_alza" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_imgfoto"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_nombre_encima_de_imagen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:lines="2"
    android:text="Esto es un polideportivo" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_checkbox_favorito"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_favorito"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thank.

Comment: Also please show your activity code

Comment: Give horizontal orientaion to linear layout

Comment: Thank. I solved it. `android:orientation="horizontal"` and `iandroid:weightSum` in `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Do I edit and write the solution in the post? or I write an answer?

Comment: Accept the already existing answer....instead of adding new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try assigning weight to linearlayout and it's children like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_imgfoto"
android:background="@color/transparent">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_nombre_encima_de_imagen"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="35dp"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textAllCaps="true"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:lines="2"
android:layout_weight="0.70"
android:text="Esto es un polideportivo" 
android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <CheckBox
android:id="@+id/infoinstalacion_fragment1_checkbox_favorito"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="true"
android:layout_weight="0.30"
android:button="@drawable/checkbox_favorito"/>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I use your answer and i have written android:orientation="horizontal" in LinearLayout

Comment: yeah but real work is done by assigning weight now you can allocate the space to both children by changing the weight number.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to add this to your LinearLayout:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Although the default orientation value for LinearLayout is horizontal,in some build version of android build tools ,there's some problems if you don't set the value.